# iOS global catch all crash

Tags: ios, crash, signals, global

I want to save some data when app crashed, which I means not only the Exception and some signal. I already implement the method

```
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&HandleException);
signal(SIGABRT, SignalHandler);
signal(SIGILL, SignalHandler);
signal(SIGSEGV, SignalHandler);
signal(SIGFPE, SignalHandler);
signal(SIGBUS, SignalHandler);
signal(SIGPIPE, SignalHandler);
```

But there are still some crash that I can not collect like send some Notification to dealloc object.

Now I have two questions:

1: There are more than 20 signals in apple documents but why most examples only use those 6 methods(  signal(_, _) ) above.

2: Is there some way that I can collect all crash ?